# Wordpress: Multi-dimensional Array in post_meta

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I am trying to make a custom voting plugin for wordpress.

I want to use post_meta to store the data.
It should have two sets of informations (user_id and a timestamp) for every vote in every post. 
So I set up an array with the data:

```
$up_vote = Array(
'ls_user_id' => $current_user->ID,
'ls_timestamp' => current_time('mysql')
);
```

The data inside the post_meta should be an Array of these Arrays.
To do this, I first create an empty Array, get the old data, and then push my first array inside like this:

```
$ls_up_votes = Array();
$ls_up_votes = get_post_meta(get_query_var('ls_id'), 'ls_up_votes');
array_push($ls_up_votes, $up_vote);
```

And later I store it like this:

```
update_post_meta(get_query_var('ls_id'), 'ls_up_votes', $ls_up_votes);
```

Now the problem:
Always when I try to get the data (and work with it), it gives me an Array which has only one element (sizeof() returns 1).

How can I store a multi-dimensional Array here?
What am I doing wrong?

thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated]

I just noticed that you're using array_push; instead you should be using [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge). Otherwise you're going to push an array into the existing array making it multi-dimensional, i.e. [see note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#61217).

You'll also want to make sure you're using the correct params in get_post_meta, see below.

---

Make sure to use return meta as an array and not a serialized string, [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Parameters) has a third paramater that should be set to TRUE if you want an the array returned.

Example:

```
get_post_meta( $post_id, 'ls_up_votes', TRUE );
```

Comment: array_push was right, exactly like i wanted. the third parameter was not needed, the description is a little bit confusing. false (default) returns a serialized array, with true it returns the unserialized string.

Comment: i think i found my mistake. because there can be more then one post_meta per post, the get_post_meta always returns an array of these meta-data, where every array element is one data set of the post-meta. so, because i used only one meta data, my own array was wrapped into another array, but accessing the first element of that array should fix my problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue as you were having. can you update your question and show use how you fixed it? thanks